# How to pass multiple values to angular 5 observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am learning angular day by day but I am stuck on a problem. I have 3 values in one component and I need to pass them to another component. I have basic understanding of observable and subscription but I have done it with 1 parameter. Now I want to broadcast 3 values

Here is my code of shopping cart.

```
additem(itemText){
  this.cart.push(itemText);
  this.itemscount = this.cart.length;
  this._data.changeCart(this.cart);
}
```

When I click on a product this function calls and it sends cart array to observable and there I broadcast the cart array

```
export class DataService {

    private cart = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
    cast = this.cart.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    changeCart(item_param) {
        this.cart.next(item_param);
        //console.log(this.cart);
    }

}
```

Now I need to pass 3 values to observable and I am confuse how to do it because I have read that we can pass only one value to observable.
I had one idea to wrap all values in an array and pass that array but I search on this but could not find that how to store multiple values in single array in angular.

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: make it a object and you use it for multiple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can make it a object and use it for multiple values

```
export class DataService {

    private cartObject = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});
    cartObjectInfo = this.cartObject.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    changeCart(cartObject) {
        this.cartObject.next(cartObject);
    }
}
```

First is get the value in BehaviourSubject

```
this.data.cartObjectInfo.subscribe(cartObject => {
   if(cartObject) this.cartObject = cartObject; 
});
this.data.changeCart({//make the full object here});
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I got your point but should I write this in additem method  this._data.changeCart(this.cart,b,c); ??
I was actually asking how to pass an object. Your answer is making object in dataservice . I want to pass it from component class. Is there any way?

Comment: then make the object in component only and pass just one argument

Comment: Exactly I was asking this. But don't know how to make object in angular2? can you provide a sample code?

Comment: Thanks for your help. My problem has been solved but I have a little problem regarding code organization.
I am sending this object 

this.cartobj = {cart_items:this.cart,items_count:this.itemscount}

I am accessing object in the component html file like this.

*ngFor="let items of cartobj.cart_items" and {{cartobj.items_count}}

But I want to assign the object values to array and simple variable in component class file and then access in html file. I have tried like this 

ngOnInit() {
  this.cart = this.cartobj.cart_items;
 }
But it is not working I am not getting any values.

Comment: Is there any way that I can access object values in component class and then send them to html template?

Comment: can you put up different question for that, and send me link, it's difficult to understand from comments, may be i'll be able to help that way

Comment: Ok, I am making another question. Please stay online.I will paste the question link here.

Answer (score 6):

You can just make an object like so:

```
a = 5;
b = 'sss';
c = new Date();

objToPass = { a: a, b: b, c: c };
```

Later, you can access object properties like objToPass.a, objToPass.b, etc.

That's the standard way of constructing JS objects.